# Хеш-таблица с открытой адресацией

Tags: c++, структуры-данных

Подскажите, как реализовать функцию удаления в хеш-таблице с открытой адресацией? 
Например,

***Хеш-таблица со значениями: 0 17 34 ...***

***Хеш-функция: x%17***

Например, я хочу удалить элемент со значением 34. Хеш-функция вернет индекс 0. 
А мне нужен индекс 2. 
Надеюсь, понятно написал.

P.S. прочитал википедию, тему с флагами не очень понял.

Comment: Не понял. Вся идея "открытой адресации"заключается в том, что индекс `0` - этот тот индекс, с которого вы **начнете поиск**. Ищите свое `34` и вы найдете индекс `2`, как вы и хотели. В чем проблема? Или вы ожидали, что хэширование сразу дает вам правильный индекс, без поиска? В общем случае так не бывает. На то оно и хэширование.

Comment: Более того, при открытой адресации вам придется пометить элемент, как удаленный, а не как свободное место - иначе последующий поиск может не найти нужный элемент, встретив пустое место и прекратив поиск...

Comment: @Harry , спасибо, разобрался